# can't open advanced setting

Tags: gnome-tweak-tool

hello every one I've just installed gnome-tweak-tool by using this code

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

After installing the Advanced setting icon appear in applications menu and when I tray to open it it seems that ubuntu opening it (from the top panel in gnome) but nothing happen.

when I check out the problem in terminal I get this message:

```
(gnome-tweak-tool:4972): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme' is not installed
```

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

I'm very thankful for anyone who help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that may not be the problem, but go to [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) and you should be able to install the `user-themes` extension it by setting the switch to <kbd>ON</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>Install</kbd>

Comment: I am already installed some extension but what I miss is this panel : [link](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7236/7290171744_e74b1e77da.jpg)

Comment: What is the output of `gnome-shell --version` & `dpkg -l gnome-tweak-tool`? Also, if you are still running `gnome-tweak-tool` and are getting the above error, try `mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.bak` to move the existing extensions.

Comment: the result for first command is GNOME Shell 3.4.1
it gives me that for second command:         Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Description
+++-==============-==============-============================================
ii  gnome-tweak-to 3.3.4-0ubuntu1 tool to adjust advanced configuration settin

Comment: I tried your last code but nothing happen. @wilf

Comment: After quick restart it works !!! thank you for your responding:).

Comment: Glad to be of help :)